# UINavigationController: Toolbar on every controller - prevent it being hidden and shown again?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, xamarin.ios

My app has a `UINavigationController`.
All the controllers I push onto the navigation controller inherit from a base class that in `ViewDidAppear()` adds a couple of `UIBarButtonItems` and sets the navigation controller's toolbar (`UINavigationController.Toolbar` property) to be visible.
Works but whenever a new controller is pushed, the buttons are faded out, just to reappear again when the new controller has been pushed.
Can I prevent the buttons to be removed in the first place?

Comment: Figured out myself...I called the SetToolbarItems() on the navigation controller instead of the view that currently gets added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out myself...I called the SetToolbarItems() on the navigation controller instead of the view that currently gets added.

Answer (score 0):

Is the whole bar fading out or just the buttons? Maybe you have set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed on a view controller?

Comment: Just the buttons were going. Is this an indicator for the property you mention?

Comment: No, that would be the whole bar disappearing I think.